# Android textview's text error

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, textview

Have 2 class.

First class:

```
public class GecmisGoruntule extends Activity 
{
    public static TextView t1;
    TextView t2;
    TextView t3;
    TextView t4;
    TextView t5;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.gecmisgoruntule);
        t1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        t2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        t3=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        t4=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        t5=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView5);
    }
}
```

My second class:

```
public class Tab3 extends Activity 
{
    yuksekPuanDb v;
    Intent intent;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tab3);
        v=new yuksekPuanDb(this);


          intent = new Intent().setClass(this, GecmisGoruntule.class);
        liste.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) 
            {

                        GecmisGoruntule.t1.setText("deneme");
                        startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

First class has 5 textviews. I get data from db in second class and i want to change my textviews's texts.Tab3 my second class.

But i get error:

```
03-29 17:04:51.570: E/AndroidRuntime(24835): FATAL EXCEPTION: main    
03-29 17:04:51.570: E/AndroidRuntime(24835):    java.lang.NullPointerException 
03-29 17:04:51.570: E/AndroidRuntime(24835): at com.its.android.Tab3$1.onItemClick(Tab3.java:56)
```

Comment: Please post the code that is causing the issue.

Comment: Take a look at line `Tab3.java:56`

Comment: Please what is in line 56?

Comment: @LisaAnne Line 56: GecmisGoruntule.t1.setText("deneme");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

you cannot set the another activity textview. pass the value to that activity get that and print it

```
    liste.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) 
        {

                    intent.putExtra("name","deneme");
                    startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

and

```
public class GecmisGoruntule extends Activity 
{
    public static TextView t1;
    TextView t2;
    TextView t3;
    TextView t4;
    TextView t5;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.gecmisgoruntule);
        t1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        t2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        t3=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        t4=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        t5=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView5);

        if(getIntent().hasExtra("name")){
           String result = getIntent().getStringExtra("name");
           t1.setText(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! that works. But i didn't understand. Why i can't set another activity textview. I create object from another class and try with it.

Comment: @c.mert because that time there is no view for that textview

Comment: @Harihan I have 1 more question. How can I change text dynamicly ?